# Tell StormCrawler to delete pages from ES-index after they have been deleted on the server

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I have the following scenario:

- An existing page gets crawled by StormCrawler
- StormCrawler adds a corresponding document to an Elasticsearch index
- The page is deleted on the server

=> The crawler "detects" the removal of the page by updating the status-index: The document gets status "FETCH_ERROR" (and after reaching the "max.fetch.errors" the status "ERROR").

Problem:
The Elasticsearch-Index still keeps the document, but since the page was deleted that doesn't make sense.

Looking at the configuration, I haven't found a way to tell StormCrawler to remove documents from the ES-index which have status "ERROR" (e. g. have been deleted).
Is there a way to accomplish this using StormCrawler or is there a reason why this is not possible?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We're planning to add a GONE status but this is not yet implemented, see [#253](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/253). In the meantime we could delete the ERROR status (even if most of them would not have been added to ES), the difficulty being that the indexing is done on the default stream i.e. docs which have been fetched and parsed whereas the status info gets sent to the *status* stream by the various bolts. We could have a bespoke bolt for deletions - it would just need the URL and nothing else: to use it we could modify AbstractStatusUpdaterBolt so that it emits the URLs to delete onto a special stream e.g. 'deletion' and connect our bespoke ES delete bolt to it. Does this make sense? Please feel free to contribute to the discussion on the link above. Thanks!

Comment: FYI have opened a new PR which implements this for Elasticsearch -> https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/pull/454
Comments and reviews welcome as usual